# How can I have elements in an Enum evaluate as their value by default?

Tags: python, enums, overriding

Is there anyway I can have an Enum like below

```
class Key(Enum):
    CUSTOMER_ID = 'c_id'
    PHONE_NUMBER = 'phone'
```

such that calling `Key.CUSTOMER_ID` evaluates to `'c_id'` by default, without the need of calling `CUSTOMER_ID.value`?

Is there any method I can override that changes what the object returned when evaluated is?

Comment: Perhaps you just need a simple `class` ?

Comment: Hehe, yep. Just remove `(Enum)` from your class definition.

Comment: Didn't even think of that! I don't see why you would ever use an Enum in Python in that case.

Comment: Only for type enforcement I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the Enum members to evaluate as their value, you need to mixin their value type:

```
class Key(str, Enum):             # note that `str` is before `Enum`
    CUSTOMER_ID = 'c_id'
    PHONE_NUMBER = 'phone'
```

and in use:

```
>>> Key.PHONE_NUMBER == 'phone'
True
```